# Creating a table from a query in MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm not sure this is possible, but the code I tried using first is:

```
mysql_query ("CREATE TABLE My_table as ( SELECT * FROM CPE LEFT JOIN Greenwich_j20 ON CPE.cust_index = Greenwich_j20.cust_index LEFT JOIN Liverpool_j20 ON CPE.cust_index = Liverpool_j20.cust_index)")
 or die ("this certainly didn't work\n");
```

The query itself works fine, and the syntax for the table works fine, but the combination is what it really doesn't like.  Does it have a problem creating a table from a left join query?

Comment: Should that `AS` [really be there](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)?

Comment: Hi Tomalak, I don't seem to get any error, just the "this certainly didn't work" when it dies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is any auto increment column in your existing tables that will be not remain auto_increment in the table to be created.

You could  try by selecting columns instead of `*` there should be an error of column Ambiguous.

Comment: Should this have been a comment?

Comment: @Tomalak: I think should not you should give some reaction time.

Comment: @Shakti: Huh? I can't understand what you said. If you're implying that I should have waited for you to complete compiling your answer, then my response is that perhaps you shouldn't post your answer until it _is_ an answer. It's not a race.

Comment: @Tomalak: That was not. I mean to say At the first sight what I thought I posted but another sight I take one another thing I posted that as well. I am not taking it like race. By the way in real life everything is race.

Comment: @Shakti: Sorry, I can't understand you. I think it's a language barrier between us.

Comment: I think I know what you mean...  There are columns in seperate tables with the same name...  So it can include them in a query, but not a table?

Comment: @Soop: when you are selecting columns with `*` query will including all the columns from all the tables mentioned in query with duplicate column name. This is fine if you have only select query but with the Create table it will give you the Duplicate column error